# Listen to onClick event for a custom component in JSF

Tags: jsf

Currently I have to create some custom components to lazily load the data from the backing bean. The `LazyTabView` component which wraps the `LazyTab` component, here is how they are used in the `xhtml`:

```java
<a:lazyTabView active-index="#{tabs.activeIndex}"
                                           cached="true"
                            >
                                <c:forEach items="#{tabs.getTabs}" var="tab"
                                           varStatus="vs">
                                    <c:if test="#{tab.rendered}">
                                        <a:lazyTab title="#{i18n[tab.title]}"
                                                   index="#{vs.index}"
                                                   action="#{tab.loadForSpecificTab(tab)}"
                                        >
                                            <h:panelGroup>
                                                <ui:include src="#{tab.xhtmlFilepath}"/>
                                            </h:panelGroup>
                                        </a:lazyTab>
                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </a:lazyTabView>
```

I only want the `LazyTabViewRender` loads once when opening a page. And I want the action of the `LazyTab` is called when the tab is clicked (which means the current tab matched the active index). I tried to search on the Internet but couldn't find a solution yet, here is what I have in the `LazyTab` component, but the `processAction` method never gets called when tab is clicked:

```java
public class LazyTab extends Tab implements ActionSource2, ActionSource, ActionListener, ClientBehaviorHolder {
  @Override
  public void processAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws AbortProcessingException {
     // I expect some method similar to this get triggered when I know indeed it's the onclick event.
    FacesContext facesContext = getFacesContext();
    UIComponent currentComponent = getCurrentComponent(facesContext);
    LazyTabView lazyTabView = null;
    if (currentComponent instanceof LazyTabView) {
      lazyTabView = (LazyTabView) currentComponent ;
    }
    if (lazyTabView != null) {
      int activeIndex = lazyTabView.getActiveIndex();
      int currentIndex = this.getIndex();
      String title = this.getTitle();
      boolean clicked = lazyTabView.isClicked(currentIndex);
      log.info("active index: {}, current index: {}, clicked: {}, title: {}", activeIndex, currentIndex, clicked, title);
      if (activeIndex == currentIndex && !clicked) {
        loadActiveTab(facesContext);
        ((LazyTabView) lazyTabView).clickTab(currentIndex);
        lazyTabView.setActiveIndex(currentIndex);
      }
    }
  }
  @Override
  public MethodExpression getActionExpression() {
    return (MethodExpression) getStateHelper().get(LazyTab.PropertyKeys.actionExpression);
  }

  @Override
  public void setActionExpression(MethodExpression actionExpression) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    getStateHelper().put(LazyTab.PropertyKeys.actionExpression, actionExpression);
  }
...

}
```

I really appreciate any help!